# SharePoint Ajax web part web.config problems

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, web-config, updatepanel

Hi I am using AJAX Extensions 1.0 in my web part.  It works great when I add it on SharePoint and everything runs fine.  I also have links to other applications which are put onto SharePoint as IFRAME's.  I run into a problem with the application inherting from my SharePoint web.config.  I get this error in the IFRAME:

Parser Error Message: The entry 'ScriptModule' has already been added.

```
Line 98:        <!-- ASP.NET AJAX -->
Line 99:        <httpModules>
Line 100:           <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
Line 101:       </httpModules>
Line 102:       <compilation debug="true">
```

I think this is because the SharePoint web.config also contains this line.  I cannot remove it from there because I need it for my web part.  I thought of adding `<clear/>` in my IFRAME applications to get around this but I have so many applications and I am not sure if there is more than once place I will need to do this.  Is there a better solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify global web.config. It can be done by WebConfigModification (don't remember full name of the class, it's been a while). There is feature Ajaxify MOSS available on CodePlex which I used and it works just fine. Take a look there. 
http://ajaxifymoss.codeplex.com/

Comment: I also just used the ajaxifymoss solution: http://macropus.net/500-internal-server-errors-when-using-jquery-ajax-in-moss-sharepoint-2007-sp1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<httpModules>
<clear />

<add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

</httpModules>`